# Send files to Windows Server

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I need to develop a C# Winforms desktop application for sport-club that also can store pictures and files.

This application will run on a few computers not all of them on the same network, and all of them will have the same content, so I can't store the files on a one pc.

I have a windows server and I would like to store the data on this server but I don't know how to do this. anything will help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you post any of the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Use for a database SQL Server (express version can be downloaded for free from msdn)  The server support multi-users and can be access across a network.

Comment: There is really no need to always develop your own app. An existing project, like http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Creating-an-image-gallery/ can easily help store pictures and files.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create shared folder on the server
2. Manipulate files and directories in this folder using System.IO.
   For example this functions:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);

if (File.Exists(destination + filename))
    File.Delete(destination + filename);

File.Move(source, destination + filename);
```

Comment: Formatting your code by prefacing each line by 4 whitespaces improves readability.